# DBpedia Lookup URIS coming with the word ''Category"

Tags: java, uri, categories, dbpedia

I found a code on Github that uses
DBpedia Lookup to send words and get candidate URIs from the DBpedia. The problem is: all the URIs come with the word `Category`. For example, for the word `Berlin` it returns:

- http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:History_of_Berlin

instead of

- http://dbpedia.org/resource/History_of_Berlin

If I put the first URI (the one with the "Category") on the browser, it doesn't show me the page corresponding to the subject "History_of_Berlin", it returns me a page that contains a list of links and where I can find the link to "History_of_Berlin". But, if I put the second URI (the one without "Category") it returns me the page corresponding to the subject "History_of_Berlin". How could I avoid having these URIs with "Category" being returned from the lookup?

#### Code

```
package com.knowledgebooks.info_spiders;

import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpException;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethod;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.GetMethod;
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.*;

/**
 * Copyright Mark Watson 2008-2010. All Rights Reserved.
 * License: LGPL version 3 (http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl-3.0.txt)
 */

// Use Georgi Kobilarov's DBpedia lookup web service
//    ref: http://lookup.dbpedia.org/api/search.asmx?op=KeywordSearch
//    example: http://lookup.dbpedia.org/api/search.asmx/KeywordSearch?QueryString=Flagstaff&QueryClass=XML&MaxHits=10

/**
 * Searches return results that contain any of the search terms. I am going to filter
 * the results to ignore results that do not contain all search terms.
 */


public class DBpediaLookupClient extends DefaultHandler {
  public DBpediaLookupClient(String query) throws Exception {
    this.query = query;
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    String query2 = query.replaceAll(" ", "+"); // URLEncoder.encode(query, "utf-8");
    HttpMethod method =
      new GetMethod("http://lookup.dbpedia.org/api/search.asmx/KeywordSearch?QueryString=" +
        query2);
    try {
      client.executeMethod(method);
      System.out.println(method);
      InputStream ins = method.getResponseBodyAsStream();
      SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
      SAXParser sax = factory.newSAXParser();
      sax.parse(ins, this);
    } catch (HttpException he) {
      System.err.println("Http error connecting to lookup.dbpedia.org");
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
      System.err.println("Unable to connect to lookup.dbpedia.org");
    }
    method.releaseConnection();
  }

  private List<Map<String, String>> variableBindings = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
  private Map<String, String> tempBinding = null;
  private String lastElementName = null;

  public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    //System.out.println("startElement " + qName);
    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("result")) {
      tempBinding = new HashMap<String, String>();
    }
    lastElementName = qName;
  }

  public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
    //System.out.println("endElement " + qName);
    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("result")) {
      if (!variableBindings.contains(tempBinding) && containsSearchTerms(tempBinding))
        variableBindings.add(tempBinding);
    }
  }

  public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
    String s = new String(ch, start, length).trim();
    //System.out.println("characters (lastElementName='" + lastElementName + "'): " + s);
    if (s.length() > 0) {
      if ("Description".equals(lastElementName)) {
        if (tempBinding.get("Description") == null) {
          tempBinding.put("Description", s);
        }
        tempBinding.put("Description", "" + tempBinding.get("Description") + " " + s);
      }
      if ("URI".equals(lastElementName)) tempBinding.put("URI", s);
      if ("Label".equals(lastElementName)) tempBinding.put("Label", s);
    }
  }

  public List<Map<String, String>> variableBindings() {
    return variableBindings;
  }
  private boolean containsSearchTerms(Map<String, String> bindings) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (String value : bindings.values()) sb.append(value);  // do not need white space
    String text = sb.toString().toLowerCase();
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(this.query);
    while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
      if (text.indexOf(st.nextToken().toLowerCase()) == -1) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
  private String query = "";
}
```

Comment: The code I'm using to get the DBpedia Lookup results is here:  https://github.com/mark-watson/java_practical_semantic_web/blob/master/src/com/knowledgebooks/info_spiders/DBpediaLookupClient.java

Comment: There's a Wikipedia article called [History of Berlin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_berlin).  There's also a category called [History of Berlin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:History_of_Berlin).  They are different things.  [Your query](http://lookup.dbpedia.org/api/search.asmx/KeywordSearch?QueryString=History%20of%20Berlin) has just two results: Museum für Naturkunde; and History of Berlin.  The second is _in_ Category:History_of_Berlin, but Category:History_of_Berlin isn't one of the results.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but the problem is that the code I'm using(see the link above), always returns me all the URIs with the word Category on them, but I'd like to be able to get the URIs without the word category.

Comment: Take a closer look at [the XML](http://lookup.dbpedia.org/api/search.asmx/KeywordSearch?QueryString=History%20of%20Berlin) that you're getting back.  While both the resource and the category are designated within `URI` elements, you want the `URI` elements that are inside of of `Result` elements, and not those inside of `Category` elements.  You just need to handle the XML you're given with the structure that it has.  You want the contents of `Result/URI` elements, and not `Result/Categories/Category/URI` elements.

Comment: (I just realized that in the links in the previous comments, I was doing a search for "History of Berlin" rather than "Berlin".  Aside from the different result set, the same observations hold.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked the author of the code, Mark Watson, for some help and he answered me:

You can make this simple code change:

```
      //if ("URI".equals(lastElementName)) tempBinding.put("URI", s);
      if ("URI".equals(lastElementName) && s.indexOf("Category")==-1
&& tempBinding.get("URI") == null) {
        tempBinding.put("URI", s);
      }
```

that is comment out 1 line, add the next three.

That's it!

Comment: Rather than commenting out, it might be better to explain this as "adding two conditions to the `if` statement.  I'm glad to see that you investigated this farther and found a solution that works for you.  Since the question doesn't contain any sample of the XML that the service returns, though, can you add some explanation as to _why_ this works (for the benefit of others who come across this question)?

Answer (score 1):

When you do a search for, e.g., "History of Berlin", you're requesting a URL like

- http://lookup.dbpedia.org/api/search.asmx/KeywordSearch?QueryString=History%20of%20Berlin

and you're getting back an XML result like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfResult 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://lookup.dbpedia.org/">
    <Result>
        <Label>Museum für Naturkunde</Label>
        <URI>http://dbpedia.org/resource/Museum_für_Naturkunde</URI>
        <Description></Description>
        <Classes></Classes>
        <Categories></Categories>
        <Templates></Templates>
        <Redirects></Redirects>
        <Refcount>155</Refcount>
    </Result>
    <Result>
        <Label>History of Berlin</Label>
        <URI>http://dbpedia.org/resource/History_of_Berlin</URI>
        <Description>
            Berlin is the capital city of Germany. Berlin is a young city by European standards, founded in the 12th century.
        </Description>
        <Classes></Classes>
        <Categories>
            <Category>
                <Label>History of Berlin</Label>
                <URI>http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:History_of_Berlin</URI>
            </Category>
            <Category>
                <Label>History of Germany by location</Label>
                <URI>http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:History_of_Germany_by_location</URI>
            </Category>
        </Categories>
        <Templates></Templates>
        <Redirects></Redirects>
        <Refcount>14</Refcount>
    </Result>
</ArrayOfResult>
```

You're right that there are `URI` elements with category URIs, e.g.,

```xml
<URI>http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:History_of_Berlin</URI>
```

but what you should note is that from the root of the document, there are

```
ArrayOfResult/Result/Categories/Category/URI
```

elements, whereas the elements that you want are

```
ArrayOfResult/Result/URI
```

elements.  You just need to process your XML a bit differently;  don't get *all* the content from *all* `URI` elements, but just from the `URI` elements that are children of `Result` elements.  I'm not all that familiar with SAX parsing, but I think the important point is that once you've entered a `Result`, you should only grab the `URI` if you haven't entered another child element of `Result`.